# Htop 'command' column too wide, how to easily see the end of it?

Tags: linux, htop

The **'Command'** column is too long most of the time, and I only care about e.g. the last 100 characters, it almost always clearly shows me what the command is about.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to move the **'Command**' column to the left, it is always the most right column.
So let's say I want to see the command responsible for highest memory usage, I have to scroll all the way to the right by pressing the right-arrow just to see because 90% (the left side) of the command is irrelevant to me.

Is there any good workaround?
If there would be a way to scroll immediately to the right-end, that would be a nice way, but the best is to not even have to do that right?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man 1 htop`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html#INTERACTIVE_COMMANDS), about <kbd>Ctrl <kbd>e</kbd></kbd> or <kbd>$</kbd>:

> Scroll right to the end of the process entry (i.e. end of line).

"End of line" means the end of the *chosen* line.

Complementary command is <kbd>Ctrl <kbd>a</kbd></kbd> or <kbd>^</kbd>:

> Scroll left to the beginning of the process entry (i.e. beginning of line).

There's also <kbd>p</kbd>:

> Show full paths to running programs, where applicable. (This is a toggle key.)

It seems your screenshot shows full paths, so <kbd>p</kbd> should shorten the lines. I cannot tell if this will make your experience substantially better though.